# Create cols based on rows pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df that can be seen below where I have the column 'sex' which indicates female/male and a column count which is the number of females/males present.

| region | organismo_nombre | sexo | conteo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Región Metropolitana de Santiago | subsecretaria de derechos humanos | F | 56 |
| Región Metropolitana de Santiago | subsecretaria de derechos humanos | M | 35 |
| Región Metropolitana de Santiago | subsecretaria de evaluación social | F | 121 |
| Región Metropolitana de Santiago | subsecretaria de evaluación social | M | 106 |

I want instead of having two rows, to have only one with column 'F' indicating the number of women and column 'M' indicating the number of men.
I did some tests with df.pivot but I still had two rows left. How could I achieve the df below?

| region | organismo_nombre | F | M |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Región Metropolitana de Santiago | subsecretaria de derechos humanos | 56 | 35 |
| Región Metropolitana de Santiago | subsecretaria de evaluación social | 121 | 106 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use pd.pivot

```
df.pivot(index=['region','organismo_nombre'], columns='sexo').reset_index()
```

```
    region                              organismo_nombre                      conteo
sexo                                                                          F     M
0   Región Metropolitana de Santiago    subsecretaria de derechos humanos    56     35
1   Región Metropolitana de Santiago    subsecretaria de evaluación social  121     106
```